# Sales Analysis :Which product is bought more by each segment in Python? trying to get the Maximum value under each segment

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a sales dataset. from which I have created dataframe which looks like [Product_segment1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIKPr.png)

I want the [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjwH5.png), I am able to get the Max values of Quantity under each segment but failed to display from which Product_code these maximum values are coming.

Code:

```py
Seg_desc = Product_segment1.groupby(['Segment']).agg({'Quantity': ['max']})
```

but this is what I'am getting as an output without Product_Code getting displayed like below:

[Seg_desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV4pK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby.idxmax()` to get the index of max value and select rows with these index.

```py
df.loc[df.groupby("Segment")["Quantity"].idxmax()]
```

Or sort on `Quantity` column descending, then drop duplicates but keep first element.

```py
df.sort_values("Quantity", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset="Segment", keep="first")
```